# Putting PrimeFaces dataTable inside Google Maps API InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, datatable

I have an a Google Map with several markers. Each marker has an infowindow that pops up with a dataTable inside. However, the dataTable that pops up doesn't show updated content for the marker being clicked, unless I close the panel the page is currently on. Below the map, I have the dataTable and it displays the correct information. The information inside the dataTable should change, depending on which marker was clicked.

I added a onclick event to the markers and for the actionlistener, I have a function that initalizes the values for the dataTable to pop up (the same one shown below the map). Again, the problem is that the dataTable that pops up does not show the updated marker values unless I close and reopen the panel the page is currently on. My guess is that the dataTable is not being updated in the DOM Tree?

Here is my code: Thankyou so much for your time. Been stuck for hours!
this.div_ is each marker on the map. myRemote is Primeface remote command that populates the bean values for the dataTable.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, 'click', function(event) {
             var ids_JsonString = JSON.stringify(ids_);
             myRemote([{
                 name: 'ids_',
                 value: ids_JsonString
             }]); //populateTables
             updateTable(); //print bean
             infowindows.setPosition(temp_center);
             infowindows.setContent(document.getElementById("dbWest:form_:normalDataTable"));
             infowindows.open(map);
```

Comment: Again, the dataTable below the map is the same dataTable that pops up by clicking on each marker! The information inside the table should change depending on which marker was clicked! (The table below the map does this and is correct. However, I want the same info/table to display on the infoWindow marker, which doesn't happen unless I close the panel that contains the dataTable and Map.) Sorry for the confusion. Really stuck :/

dbWest:form_:normalDataTable is the ID of the dataTable below the map. I am appending this DOM node to be the content of the infoWindow for each marker.

Comment: Are you using Primefaces `p:gmap` component to display the MAP?
If YES the you should be using `p:gmapInfoWindow` for info window and which gives you option of `overlaySelect` event on `p:gmap`.